# Is there a XHR request/response manager for Dojo

Tags: jquery, dojo, xmlhttprequest

I was wondering if Dojo (or any of its extensions) provides a (reliable) XHR request/response manager that would allow me to queue, block and retry calls when needed. Something similar to [AJAX Queue/Cache/Abort/Block Manager v. 3.0](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/) for jQuery.

Comment: BTW - with deferred it can abort the request or cancel it - you just need to pair it with an event.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, Dojo deferred. Any i/o - ajax calls (xhrPut/xhrPost/xhrGet etc..) returns a deferred call, you can add them into a list of deferred calls, and if you want, independently from the success of failure you can call a function.

i.e. 
var deferred = dojo.xhrPost({...});

deferred.addCallback(function(data) { ...}); // it execute independetly from success or failure

look at [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/xhrPost.html) this is an example of xhrPost, if you look at the code it says that returns a deferred object.